# Does google index content of datalist tags

Tags: seo, google

Does google index content of datalist tags?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Search crawler is [based on Chrome 41](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering), and [Chrome 41 supports datalist elements](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist), so it would stand to reason that Google crawls datalist elements.

Comment: Google may well _crawl_ and understand `datalist` elements, but does it actually index the content contained within them (which is what the question is asking)? Does Google consider the otherwise "hidden" text inside a `datalist` as on-page content? When a user visits the page, they don't see the content inside a datalist - which may have nothing to do with the page content - so I have my doubts whether Google would actually index this or, at best, put much weight to it (it feels like something that would be open to abuse)?

Comment: Although "Chrome 41 supports datalist elements", it is listed as having only "partial support" - there would seem to be "a bug where long lists of items are unscrollable resulting in unselectable options".

Comment: Can confirm it works,I ranked a page for some keywords that appear only in a datalist tag.